# C++ generic way to define multiple functions with a template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, template-specialization

In C++ is it possible to define multiple methods based of the number of template parameters provided? Similar to how variadic functions work?

With functions I can do

```
template <class ...Args>
struct VariadicFunctionCallback {
    typedef std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<Args>...)> variadic;
};
```

But what I want to know is if I could do something similar but to create multiple functions instead of multiple arguments

```
template <class ...FunctionArg>
class Example {
     void Function(FunctionArg)...
}
```

Which would then allow me to do something like

```
template <>
class Example<int, float> {
    void Function(int i) {
        ...
    }

    void Function(float f) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And if this is possible what are the advantages over my current setup which is like

```
template<class EventType>
class EventHandler {
public:
    void HandleEvent(const std::shared_ptr<EventType>& event) {
    }
};

class ExampleEvent : public Event<ExampleEvent> {

};

class ExampleHandler : public EventHandler<ExampleHandler>, EventHandler<Events::ShutdownEvent> {
public:
    void HandleEvent(const std::shared_ptr<ExampleEvent> &event);

    void HandleEvent(const std::shared_ptr<Events::ShutdownEvent> &event);
};
```

**--Edit--**
I ended up with a mix if the two solutions.
It is probably not the best and I will continue to play around with and improve it overtime.

```
template <class EventType>
class BaseEventHandler {
public:
    EventIdentifier GetIdentifier() const {
        return EventType::GetIdentifier();
    }

    virtual void HandleEvent(const std::shared_ptr<EventType> &event) = 0;
};

template<class EventType, class ...EventTypes>
class EventHandler: public BaseEventHandler<EventTypes>... {

};
```

Which then allows me to do

```
class EventListener: public EventHandler<ShutdownEvent, MousePosEvent, WindowCloseRequestEvent> {
    void HandleEvent(const std::shared_ptr<ShutdownEvent> &event);
    void HandleEvent(const std::shared_ptr<MousePosEvent> &event);
    void HandleEvent(const std::shared_ptr<WindowCloseRequestEvent> &event);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you can make `Example` a sort of recursive self-inheritancing class; something as

```
    template <typename ...>
    struct Example
     {
       // dummy Function() to end the recursion
       void Function ()
        { }
     };

    template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
    struct Example<T0, Ts...> : public Example<Ts...>
     {
       using Example<Ts...>::Function;

       void Function (T0 const &)
        { };
     };
```

So you can write

```
int main ()
 {
   Example<int, long, float>  e0;

   e0.Function(0);
   e0.Function(0L);
   e0.Function(0.0f);
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> Could a specialisation then be preformed on top of this?

Do you mean something as follows?

```
template <typename ...>
struct Example
 {
   // dummy Function() to end the recursion
   void Function ()
    { }
 };

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct Example<T0, Ts...> : public Example<Ts...>
 {
   using Example<Ts...>::Function;

   void Function (T0 const &)
    { };
 };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Example<float, Ts...> : public Example<Ts...>
 {
   void FunctionFloat (float const &)
    { };
 };

int main ()
 {
   Example<int, long, float>  e0;

   e0.Function(0);
   e0.Function(0L);
   e0.FunctionFloat(0.0f);
   //e0.Function(0.0f); // compilation error
 }
```

Comment: Could a specialisation then be preformed on top of this?

Comment: Ie
`
    template<>
    struct Example: public Example<int, long, float> {
        
        void Function (int i) {}
        void Function (long l) {}
        void Function (float f) {}
    }
`

Comment: Is `using Example<Ts...>::Function;` needed? As far as I can tell public base functions can be accessed without namespace.

Comment: @Cethric - yes; but I suggest something as in modified answer

Comment: @GillBates - Well... `Example<Ts...>::Function` isn't exactly an access through namespace. Yes: it's needed; try to comment it and you'll see some errors. You're right: usually, public base function can be accessed without that using. But when you define a method in derived class, you hide the method with same name inherited from base classes; also if they have a different signature. So, in this case, you have to use that `using` to make visible inherited methods.

Comment: @max66 that is not quite what I meant, however that is good to know. What I want to know is instead of doing: `void Function (T0 const &)` could I do `void Function (float const&)`? as shown in the third code block of my question?

Comment: @Cethric - not sure to understand what you want but... yes, it's possible.

Comment: @max66 I don't understand why the compiler doesn't complain about multiple definitions of a function if I use it like `Example<int, int> e;`. Wouldn't that essentially generate two methods with the same signature and the call become ambiguous?

Comment: @qutab - Yes and no. Yes: there are generated two methods with the same signature `Function(int const &)`; the first one in `Example<int, int>` and the second one in `Example<int>`. And no: the call doesn't become ambiguous; because `Example<int, int>` inherit from `Example<int>`; so the `Function(int const &)` method in `Example<int, int>` hide the one on `Example<int>`. The `using`, in this case, doesn't works because un-hide methods and members with same name; but a method (or member) in `Example<int, int>` hide equally a method (member) with the same signature (of the same name).

Answer (score 3):

[This answer start's with max66's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50082773/27678), more or less

We start with a class that uses recursive inheritance to implement our function. In my case, I chose `operator()`, and I used a variadic using declaration to bring all children `operator()` into scope:

```
namespace detail{
    template<class T, class... U>
    struct ExampleImpl : ExampleImpl<U>...{
        using ExampleImpl<U>::operator()...;
        void operator()(T _arg){/*...*/}
    };
}
```

Where my answer diverges from max66's is in that we'll use this `ExampleImpl` class to **compose** our `Example` class:

```
template<class... T>
class Example
{
public:
    template <class U>
    void Function(U arg)
    {
        impl(arg);
    }
    
    void Function(float arg) 
    {
        /*Your specialization code*/
    }
private:
    detail::ExampleImpl<T...> impl;
};
```

I do it this way for 2 reasons:

1. This inheritance is an implementation-detail and something you'd want to hide from clients.
2. *Now we can easily specialize our `Function` function for whatever type we want because we always have a choice in whether to call through to our instance of `ExampleImpl` or not.

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JX5RZRCi0FZ3bBq7)

If `ExampleImpl` needs to use member variables of your `Example` class, then you can either turn `ExampleImpl` into a full-fledged [PIMPL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) class, or modify its constructor or `operator()` to accept additional arguments as a form of [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

*You could just as easily perform full class specialization where `float` is one of the template parameters in the specialization, and define your own `Function`. Or you could use a form of [tag dispatching](https://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#tag_dispatching) to hide the `float` version unless it was in the list of template types.

#### [Tag dispatch demonstration](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FCRlHsS24ih8bmgk)